# How to Create an Android Application with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm new to Android and very unfamiliar with Eclipse. I'm trying to get a simple Hello World project started, as per

[Developing In Eclipse, with ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html)

I've downloaded the latest Eclipse dev environment (64 bit), the latestes JVM (64 bit) and the latest Android SDK.

I've used Android SDK and AVD Manager to create an AVD targeting Honeycomb to Windows 7 64 bit. I did the default install for everything.

When I start Eclipse, I click File > New > Project I expected to see a folder for Android, but there's nothing there except the project optins that were there when I first installed Eclipse: General, CVS, Java & Examples

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Can somebody tell me if there's a way to get this going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install [the ADT plugin for Eclipse?](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing)

Comment: is that the Google Plugin? There's no link for 'ADT'. Does it have a different name?

Comment: See the link. You have to add the Google download site to Eclipse software updater, then you can download the plugin via Eclipse.